# is there a way to make this css style simple

Tags: html, css, optimization, shorthand

```
border-right:1px solid #8fa6b9;
border-bottom:1px solid #8fa6b9;
border-left:1px solid #2b5a82;
border-top:1px solid #2b5a82;
```

the right is the same as the bottom......

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
border       : 1px solid;
border-color : #2b5a82 #8fa6b9 #8fa6b9 #2b5a82;
```

Comment: It should be: `border-color : #2b5a82 #8fa6b9 #8fa6b9 #2b5a82;` It goes clockwise starting from the top.

Comment: cwolves,your answer is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

```
border: 1px solid #8fa6b9;
border-left-color: #2b5a82;
border-right-color: #2b5a82;
```

Try this, this one is more meaningful.

Comment: I'm not sure about "more meaningful".  It certainly works and may be easier to read by people new to CSS, but getting used to "top, right, bottom, left" syntax is useful and easy to read once you understand it.

Comment: i know its a bit lengthy. but i said that its meaningful because it really helps starters to grasp css knowledge quickly. :P thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The settings goes clockwise. So first number is up, second right, third bottom and the fourth number is the left border.

Answer (score 0):

border       : 1px solid #8fa6b9;

border-left-color : #2b5a82;

border-top-color : #2b5a82;